# how can i run my flutter application on emulator?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

I'm trying to run my `flutter` application on an emulator but it doesn't work, I'm using Visual Studio Code (vscode) and when I choose "run without debugging" it show me the emulator only without my application working on it (like a normal phone). I tried to create another emulator and it still not working, I also tried to delete the emulator and recreating it and it still not workimg too! I'm sure my code is correct 100% because it works with my friend perfectly.

How can I fix this problem please?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try the following:

-Run Android Studio and VS Code as administrator.

-If the above does not work, uninstall and reinstall emulators.

-**The best alternative:** Use your android phone and connect it to the PC (https://youtu.be/IV20QYaae3c) and use it as an emulator. This fixed the problem for me. I use my phone as an emulator.